# Finding the highest value task. Got everything but that

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

Trying to make it so Largest Task is pointed out in the print. Got everything else just need to able to grab the Largest Task.

```
def main ():
    print("*** TIME MANAGEMENT ASSISTANT ***") NumberOfTasks = int(input("Number of tasks: "))
    total = 0.0
    TotalHour = 0.0
    Day = 0.0
    Minute = 0.0
    EndTimeMinute = 0.0
    EndTimeHour = 0.0
    EndTimeDay = 0.0
    RemainingHour = 0.0
    AverageMinutes = 0.0print("What time will you start (on a 24-hour clock)? ")
    StartHour = int(input("Hour: "))
    StartMinute = int(input("Minute: "))
    for i in range (NumberOfTasks):
        TaskName = input("Task description: ")
        TaskTime = int(input("How many minutes will this task take? "))
        total = int(total + TaskTime)
        TotalHour = int(total//60)
        Minute = int(total%60)
        Day = int(TotalHour//24)
        RemainingHour = int(TotalHour%24)
        EndTimeDay = Day
        EndTimeHour = TotalHour + StartHour
        if EndTimeHour > 24:
            EndTimeHour = int(total%60)
        EndTimeMinute = Minute + StartMinute
        AverageMinutes = float(total//NumberOfTasks)
    print("TOTAL TIME:", Day, "day(s)", RemainingHour, "hour(s)", Minute, "minute(s)")
    print("END TIME: ", "In ", EndTimeDay, " day(s) at ", EndTimeHour, ":", EndTimeMinute,sep="")
    print("LONGEST TASK: ")
print("AVERAGE TASK LENGTH:", round(AverageMinutes,2),  "minutes")
```

Comment: Please read your own code and make sure it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You need to record the time of each "task," and then calculate the longest after the loop by sorting. To implement this way, you need to ensure task names are unique, so I've added a line of code to do that (all additions are commented):

```
def main():
    print("*** TIME MANAGEMENT ASSISTANT ***")
    NumberOfTasks = int(input("Number of tasks: "))
    total = 0.0
    TotalHour = 0.0
    Day = 0.0
    Minute = 0.0
    EndTimeMinute = 0.0
    EndTimeHour = 0.0
    EndTimeDay = 0.0
    RemainingHour = 0.0
    AverageMinutes = 0.0
    print("What time will you start (on a 24-hour clock)? ")
    StartHour = int(input("Hour: "))
    StartMinute = int(input("Minute: "))

    # create a dictionary to store time for each task
    task_times = {}

    for i in range (NumberOfTasks):
        TaskName = input("Task description: ")

        # ensure task name is unique
        while TaskName in task_times.keys():
            TaskName = input("Task description has already been used. Please enter a unique description: ")


        TaskTime = int(input("How many minutes will this task take? "))
        total = int(total + TaskTime)
        TotalHour = int(total//60)
        Minute = int(total%60)
        Day = int(TotalHour//24)
        RemainingHour = int(TotalHour%24)
        EndTimeDay = Day
        EndTimeHour = TotalHour + StartHour
        if EndTimeHour > 24:
            EndTimeHour = int(total%60)
        EndTimeMinute = Minute + StartMinute
        AverageMinutes = float(total//NumberOfTasks)

        # record time for this task in the dictionary
        task_times[TaskName] = TaskTime


    print("TOTAL TIME:", Day, "day(s)", RemainingHour, "hour(s)", Minute, "minute(s)")
    print("END TIME: ", "In ", EndTimeDay, " day(s) at ", EndTimeHour, ":", EndTimeMinute, sep="")

    # calculate longest task by sorting by time and taking the last item
    longest_task_name, longest_task_length = sorted(task_times.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[-1]

    print("LONGEST TASK: {}".format(longest_task_name))
    print("AVERAGE TASK LENGTH:", round(AverageMinutes,2),  "minutes")
```